# How can I write unsigned type to file in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I have some 48 bit unsigned numbers that I want to write to a file from my VHDL testbench. Unfortunately, the way I have always done it in the past, converting to integer, does not work for numbers larger than 32 bits.

Here is how I have always done it with numbers smaller than 32 bits.

```
write(L=>result_line, value=>to_integer(unsigned(C_combo_out)));
```

Here is what I would like to do but the unsigned type is not supported.

```
write(L=>result_line, value=>unsigned(C_combo_out));
```

`C_combo_out` is a 48 bit std_logic_vector that represents an unsigned integer. Note, I really want numbers in the output file, not strings of '1' and '0'.

Comment: Sorry there were some faults in my solution. I changed log10ceil to div_ceil(length, 3) to approximate the result length. A version that trims leading zeros was uploaded to [PoC.Strings](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/strings.vhdl#L273-L307)

Answer (score 1):

So you need numbers of base 10?

Exporting large numbers of base 16 would be very simple, especially if another tool or language post-processes your output. Numbers of base 10 and larger than 2**31 need special treatment.

You could use the [double dabble algorithmn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble) to convert such large numbers into a BCD representation and than convert the BCD number to ASCII for file export.

This should convert large std_logic_vectors to decimal numbers:

```
function raw_format_slv_dec(slv : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR) return STRING is
  function div_ceil(a : NATURAL; b : POSITIVE) return NATURAL is  -- calculates: ceil(a / b)
  begin
    return (a + (b - 1)) / b;
  end function;

  variable Result     : STRING(1 to div_ceil(slv'length, 3));

  subtype TT_BCD      is INTEGER range 0 to 31;
  type TT_BCD_VECTOR  is array(natural range <>) of TT_BCD;

  variable Temp   : TT_BCD_VECTOR(div_ceil(slv'length, 3) - 1 downto 0)    := (others => 0);
  variable Carry  : T_UINT_8;

begin
  for i in slv'range loop
    if (slv(i) = '0') then
      Carry      := 0;
    else
      Carry      := 1;
    end if;
    for j in Temp'reverse_range loop
      Temp(j)    := Temp(j) * 2 + Carry;
      if (Temp(j) > 9) then
        Carry    := 1;
        Temp(j)  := Temp(j) - 10;
      else
        Carry    := 0;
      end if;
    end loop;
  end loop;

  for i in Result'range loop
    Result(i)    := CHARACTER'val(to_integer(Temp(Temp'high - i + 1)));
  end loop;

  -- trim leading zeros, except the last
  return Result;
end function;
```

An extended version was uploaded to [PoC's strings package](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/strings.vhdl#L273-L307).

## Appendix: Run a testbench on PoC.strings package

The PoC-Library comes with testbenches, so you can run it from console. There are 4 simple steps, which need to be executed:

1. [Download PoC](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/wiki/Download)
2. Configure your preferred simulator tool chain(s):

   ```
   cd <PoCRoot>
   ./poc.sh --configure
   ```
3. [Setup](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/wiki/Integration#3-creating-pocs-my_config-and-my_project-files):
   Create a my_project.vhdl in `<PoCRoot>/tb/common/` from template `<PoCRoot>/src/common/my_project.vhdl.template`. Configure the two constants with that file.
4. [Run the simulation](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/wiki/Testbenches#quick-example):

   ```
   cd <PoCRoot>/tb
   ./testbench.sh --isim PoC.common.strings -g
   ```

If you run the simulation without `-g` it should look like this:

[image: Simulating on console]
(clickable)

If you run the simulation with option `-g`, it will run in GUI-mode and look like this:

[image: iSim GUI with constants]
(clickable)

**Further information:**
- [List of used files](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/tb/common/strings_tb.files)
- [Testbench](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/tb/common/strings_tb.vhdl)

If you have further questions, please refer to the [AUTHORS](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/AUTHORS) file and contact me or my colleagues directly.

Comment: Paebbels, that function is very clever but surely a language designed to describe digital logic has a more direct way to print large numbers base 10.  64 bit numbers are not rare.

Comment: In my opinion, there is no other or shorter way, because VHDL can't handle numbers above 2^31-1. I never said that 64 bit numbers are rare, but exporting number greater than 2^32 in decimal is unusual, therefore the hexadecimal format exists...

Comment: Well I tried using your PoC library to gain the ability to print large numbers to files in decimal format but I never got your raw_format_slv_dec() function to work in my simulation. I received a variety of run-time errors about indexes out of range.  Do you have a working example where you use this function with the write() function?

Comment: @Pedro_Uno I extended my answer with an appendix, on how to run PoC's testbenches and how to run the strings testbench. The wiki pages on GitHub are new, so please disregard my faults or report those, so I can fix them :).

Comment: [rant alert] I am really surprised by how slowly digital design tools have improved over the last 20 years.  Fiddling around with these low level HDL's must come to an end. Even medium sized FPGA's are gigantic now.  The very fact that one must take a day to figure out how to write 48 bit unsigned decimal numbers to a text file is shameful.  The write() function should have been overloaded to handle signed and unsigned types 15 years ago. There needs to be a better way to get new features pushed upstream into the tools the way gnu and linux do. I am tired of all this fiddling.